# Laravel Optimize Slow Cache (Laravel Livewire)

Tags: laravel, redis, httpresponse, laravel-livewire, amazon-elasticache

I'm running a project using Laravel + Livewire + AWS ElastiCache + AWS RDS.

In Laravel Livewire page, when I click one button, it loads data (list of users) from server and renders.

I'm using ElastiCache (PHP Redis) and it will get data from cache.

The thing is it's very slow to get data even from cache.
Page is being updated after about 10 - 15s and it's almost same as I get data from DB query.
I checked query count using Debugbar and there isn't any query count. (means it gets data from Cache.)

I can see when data (user list) is very large, it loads very slower on server.
For small data, it loads faster.

I can see it works faster on my local. means - I love Cache on my local as it loads 10 times faster than doing without it.

But when I deployed it on server, it takes almost same time with even Cache.

I debug how long it takes to get data from cache.

```
$start = microtime(true)
$data = cache()->get("users_data");
$end = microtime(true)

dd($end - $start);
```

It's only 0.02s.

But why does it take so long time to send this data to frontend?

I'm not quite sure but I think it's related to server's data transfer bandwidth?

Comment: "I can see when data (user list) is very large, it loads very slower on server." How large are we talking about? If you've got a million rows with a lot of content, Redis is gonna be a little slow just because of all the network traffic back and forth. Consider pagination and using `select()` to only get the columns you really need. You should also look at the CloudWatch dashboards for your cache tier to see what bandwidth and CPU usage looks like.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's not that large though. It's about 150 rows x 5 array. And it loads fast on my local without any delay.

Comment: Local-to-local requests have *much* more bandwidth than is available between EC2 and ElastiCache. The debugbar has a Cache tab; how many Cache requests are you making in there? I'd again encourage you to look at the ElastiCache metrics in CloudWatch.

Comment: Can't see cache tab. I think it's only one or two. Looking at cloudwatch metrics

Comment: Check `config/debugbar.php` to enable the Cache monitoring.